# Report row level formula does not work

Tags: reporting, shield-encryption

I have a simple row level formula on an Activity Report

```
CASE(Subject,
     'Foo','1',
     'Bar','2', 
     'n/a'
    )
```

But, given these Task records

```
Id       Subject
--       ------- 
...       Foo
...       Bar
```

the value of the row level formula is always 'n/a'

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the issue was the object field of the row level formula was Shield platform-encrypted and comparisons against encrypted fields [are not permitted in formulas](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_pe_formulas.htm?search_text=formula)

- The SFDC Report Row Level formula editor won't tell you this!?!  You get a valid formula indicator.
- If you paste the formula into a custom field on Activity, the custom field formula editor *will* tell you that you can't use CASE or equality operators on encrypted fields.

Your workaround will depend on your application, for me, I needed a separate field on Activity that was not encrypted that I could guarantee would never be populated with data that was PII/PHI.  *(Only activities on some objects have protected subjects; activities on other objects don't -- but the Shield encryption applies to all Activities, regardless of parent)*